# how to remaster ubuntu 14.10 (currently installed )

Tags: customization, custom-distributions, remastersys

i want to remaster my ubuntu as I want to create my spin of ubuntu for my friends . I was not able to install remastersys . I  used many scripts like relinux and linux live but no result . Is there a way to remaster ubuntu the hard way (mannually without gui ) if there is please help me . I read the uck documentation but every time I build it it exceeds the 4gb limit , so I want to remaster my current install

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using pinguy builder ,
This is the script used to build Pinguy OS, The script creates a livecd of the installed system and works with *buntu. You can either make a distributable livecd or a backup of your system :

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pinguy-os/files/ISO_Builder/